# Short story about a bullied boy winning a rock throwing fight because he can throw rocks so that they curve

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I read a short story back in the 2001/2002 time frame while I was in middle school. It may have been assigned reading, or part of a text book, or a library book I can't remember. I was reading it during class at the time (7th or 8th grade, USA). I believe it was a literature class. I only remember one specific scene, which may actually be the entirety of the story.

School bullies pick on a certain kid and begin throwing either snowballs with rocks in them, or just rocks at him. I feel like this was a common occurrence in the story setting. There may have been snow piles and banks because the main character takes cover. He ends up winning the fight (I think) because he has practiced throwing rocks so that they curve (they curve because they are somewhat flattened and thrown at an angle). He is accurate enough to curve the rocks around the cover the bullies are using, and beats them even though there are many bullies. The fact that he could curve the rock so accurately was a big deal in the story.

I remember it feeling somewhat dystopian almost in a "The Giver" kind of way.

Please help me find the name of this story or where I read it.

Comment: I am almost sure that I also read this around 1994.